# CPU usage periodically plummets, netflix pauses

Tags: performance, cpu

I've been trying to make an HTPC from an old DELL lattitude E6410. Streaming is fine on firefox (a bit choppy but not bad) but every now and then netflix pauses. I've watched the system monitor and I can see when it happens there is a drop in CPU usage from about 25% down to about 3% and the download simultaneously drops out too.

I've checked with my Mac and it streams fine, so it's not the router, nor is it netflix itself. It happens on other  streams too, like catchup TV sites.

Here's a screenshot of the sysmon. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ7b2.png)

So any ideas? Is this an ubuntu problem? Or a hardware problem?

Do I just needed a newer computer?

output of free -h
`total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7G        1.4G        796M         81M        1.5G        2.0G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G`

thanks

Comment: I've been watching the CPU speed. It slowly rises to more than 3000Hz and then plummets back to ~1700Hz, and that's when the pause is. The max speed is 2666Hz so I'm guessing it "realises" it's going too fast and has a little break,

Comment: You might want to try enabling hardware acceleration in Firefox (you can search about it on web) or switch to Chromium. Make sure you have installed graphics driver. If you need help with either of them you can tag me here.

Comment: Show me `free -h`. In your BIOS, or via an app, is there a setting to throttle CPU performance via clock freq?

Comment: Thanks Edward, I've turned HW accel on and off and on again. Makes no difference. .^_^. Nvidia driver is installed.

Comment: heynnema, thanks for your help. I'm interstate for Christmas at the mo, so I'll send you free -h (but won't that just display the help?) next year. Sorry about that. There's a speedstep setting in the BIOS I've turned off. I think that's the only frequency throttling setting.  I'll have another look when I get home.

Comment: @heynnema
I've put the output from free -h in the original post

Comment: `free -h` shows memory/swap usage in human readable format. Other than being a low memory, not-enough-swap machine, try using the `free -h` or `swapon` commands in `terminal` and see how much swap is used when the machine slows down.

Comment: Thanks @heynnema I did watch -n1 swapon and the swap usage stayed at 0. I also watched top while streaming but all that showed me was that when it pauses the top processes' cpu usage drops to about 6%...no surprises there.

Comment: Well, it's not swap. Other than a cpu-throttle or turbo-boost action, then I don't have any other ideas for you. Check /var/log/syslog* around the time of the slowdown and see if you find any clues there.

Comment: thanks @heynnema. I think it might be something peculiar to Dell laptops of that vintage. I've found gamers complaiining of the cpu dropping out when they were streaming games too, which makes me wonder if it's something to do with the network card.